# Get range of dates for movie rental

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a movie rental application. The company would enter the movie rent date and movie rent end date. Dates can overlap (as you can have many customers). The data in the db is stored as

```
RecordID    FromRentDate            ToRentDate
   1      2016-10-06 18:00:00.000   2016-10-06 20:00:00.000
   2      2015-10-06 18:00:00.000   2015-10-06 20:00:00.000 
   3      2015-09-29 16:00:00.000   2015-09-30 17:00:00.000 
   4      2015-09-11 00:00:00.000   2015-09-11 00:00:00.000 
   5      2015-09-09 10:00:00.000   2015-09-09 14:30:00.000
```

When the user selects a date (using standard .Net controls) the following code is called

```
        IEnumerable<Event> LiveDates = DataContext.Events.Where(d => d.StartDate.Value >= DateTime.Now);
        IEnumerable<DateTime> AllLiveDates = null;

        if (LiveDates != null && LiveDates.Count() > 0)
        {
            DateTime FromRentDate = LiveDates.Where(f => f.StartDate.HasValue).Min(f => f.StartDate).Value;
            DateTime ToRentDate = LiveDates.Where(t => t.EndDate.HasValue).Max(f => f.EndDate).Value;

            AllLiveDates = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                         .Select(x => FromRentDate.Date.AddDays(x))
                         .TakeWhile(x => x <= ToRentDate.Date)
                         .Where(x => DataContext.Events.Any(c => x >= c.StartDate && x <= c.EndDate));
        }

        return AllLiveDates.ToList();
```

What i would like to happen is when a user selects a date, it gets all the dates from the selected date, to the end date including any inclusive dates where the movie is also out so using the above data, if i select todays date I should get all records back and the dates should be listed as:

```
2015-09-09
2015-09-11
2015-09-29
2015-09-30
2015-10-06 .... etc
```

Notice how `2015-09-29`, `2015-09-30` are included but `2015-09-30` is **not** a start date. This is because the length of this movie rental is for 2 days (29 and 30 September).

The problem i am experiencing with the above code is that it only returns 1 date. Debugging it it seems to go into AllLiveDates code and something is removing the other dates but not sure what?

Comment: off-topic comment: replace `LiveDates.Count() > 0` with `LiveDates.Any()`

Comment: Nope, that didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you are comparing a date value with a date and time.

Take for example the date `2015-09-09`.  When you compare that to the `DateTime` values in your table you should get zero matches, because the `DateTime` value `2015-09-09 00:00:00.0000` does not lie between the start and end `DateTime` values of any of your data points.

You will need to strip the time portions of your data points to get the comparison to work the way you want.  Fortunately LINQ to SQL supports the `.Date` property of `DateTime` values, so this should work:

Try this:

```
AllLiveDates = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .Select(x => FromRentDate.Date.AddDays(x))
    .TakeWhile(x => x <= ToRentDate.Date)
    .Where(x => DataContext.Events.Any(c => x >= c.StartDate.Value.Date && x <= c.EndDate.Value.Date));
```

Just don't look at the generated SQL... it's not pretty.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
var dateList = new List<DateTime>();
foreach (var ld in LiveDates)
{
    for (var dt = ld.StartDate.Date; dt <= ld.EndDate.Date; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
    {
        dateList.Add(dt);
    }
}
dateList = dateList.Distinct().ToList();
dateList = dateList.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
```

Comment: While this does actually produce a list of dates that the item is reserved, it doesn't explain why the original code didn't work.  Not a bad answer though.